# Html.HiddenFor sporadically not getting set w/ model information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

We're having an issue with Html.HiddenFor in MVC3 *occasionally* not getting bound properly. We can't reproduce it at all, but we're seeing nullrefs come through in our logging and it's driving us absolutely nuts.

We have the following model and controller structure:

```
public class DummyController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReturnAPage(int NumericID)
    {
        //NumericID should never be 0 or negative, but let's check to make sure
        if (NumericID < 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("TracyJordanStabbingRobot");
        }
        return View("DummyView", new DummyViewModel(NumericID));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TakePageSubmission(DummyViewModel model)
    {
        //AnObject relies on having a non-zero ID
        ComplexObject AnObject = new ComplexObject(model.NumericID);
        AnObject.UseMe();
    }
}

public class DummyViewModel
{

     public DummyViewModel() {}
     public DummyViewModel(int ID)
     {
         NumericID = ID;
     }

     public int NumericID { get; set; }
}
```

... and the following view structure:

DummyView.cshtml

```
@model DummyViewModel
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>THIS IS A VIEW!</p>
        <form id="DummyViewForm" action="/RouteTo/TakePageSubmission" method="post">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialDummyView", Model)
            <input type="submit" value="Submit This!" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

_PartialDummyView.cshtml

```
@model DummyViewModel
   <p>Heard you like views...</p>
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumericID)
```

Considering we're checking for less-than-zero values in the initial controller action, it stands to reason that `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumericID)` should never have a less-than-zero value.

That being said, when we get to using `AnObject` in the `TakePageSubmission` action, we're getting null reference errors.

When we dug into logging the `model.NumericID` value, we're seeing it come through as zero, which *shouldn't be possible* considering the DummyView can only be accessed with a non-zero value.

We're a little stumped and since we can't reliably reproduce the issue, we have *no* idea what could possibly be causing it. Has anyone run into something like this before?

Edit: We are doing ModelState validation on the form post, but we're not checking to see if the NumericID coming through is 0. When we did check for that, the model came through as invalid, which just proves that the HiddenFor is getting set improperly. Furthermore, the route to the page actually *includes* the NumericID, so for example, we've seen this happen on:

http://our.site.com/RouteToReturnAPage/1736/

...where the parameter for the action is clearly set, the model is constructed correctly, but for some unknown reason the HiddenFor NumericID value is 0. It's really baffling.

Comment: Is it an external web site? Could it be someone attempting something untoward? or a spider or something?

Comment: Could it be that you are just missing a `return` in front of `RedirectToAction("TracyJordanStabbingRobot");`?

Comment: sorry, initial code was typed with some haste. fixed those errors.

Comment: @Liam nope, everything is within our site's control.

Comment: From the code you've added. I can't see how this is possible. So there must be something else going on here. without seeing the rest of your code it's going to be very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @Liam, excepting the fact that it's pseudocode and not actual snippets, that's one-to-one with what we're doing in production. Like you said, it *shouldn't* be possible - but it's happening.

Comment: shouldn't your `TakePageSubmission` be marked with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @Liam that is probably the reason.  Without HttpPost, I can simply goto http://../Dummy/TakePageSubmission and completely bypass the form submission.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wondered. Didn't know if this was just a typeo in the question or not though.

Comment: Sorry to keep editing it - in production it is in fact marked w/ post only.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that NumericID on the controller is not zero because of that check. Next stop is at the constructor, no possibility of change there too. Not on the view and not on the partial view as well because these are just assignments.

My suggestion in cases like this is that you get the source code for the asp.net MVC and run alongside your app, and do a check for zeros on the calling of HiddenFor. What if you use Hidden instead of HiddenFor, do you still get this kind of error?

Comment: Upon skimming our logs, it looks like we may not be getting any posted data whatsoever. Trying to figure out if that's in fact the case.

Answer (score 3):

Your default 0 value bindings are from MVC View'ing to the same page after post, thinking it is reloading the same view due to an error during the post. The correct binding will occur on a load/action call to a different Action call.

There is a hack workaround, to `ModelState.Clear();` before you reload the View.

Also, not using the Helpers to create the hidden fields at all, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.NumericID" id="NumericID" name="NumericID" />
```

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing default constructor in your model. Without it applicaiton throws exception when binding.

You can reproduce the error by editing the hidden field on client side. So user can change id to 0 or any other value. If you aren't running you application on distributed enviroment then use TempData to pass the id between actions. This way you will keep id safe from data tampering.

```
TempData["NumericID"] = NumericID;
```

Comment: Sorry, like I said I typed the code in some haste. There is a default constructor.